# Verifying the integrity of a file that has been transfered from an unreliable medium

Tags: linux, hard-drive, video, file-transfer

I am attempting to transfer a very large amount of home video files to / from an external 1 TB hard drive. this hard drive was bought from walmart for $70 and is the biggest headache i have ever experienced. it likes to randomly disconnect in the middle of what it is doing. Sadly it is the only thing i have that can transfer that much data to another PC (without devoting way too much time to the effort).

So how do i verfy the integrity of the files both on the HD and once transfered to the second PC? Is there even a way to do this without actually watching or redundantly encoding them? As i said, they are video files (.avi).

I would prefer a method that is distro-independant since this is all coming about from the fact that i am switching from Kubuntu to Arch. I could work with the files from a live ISO if needed but would prefer if i didn't have to do that

**EDIT**

I should clarify that the files are currently on the internal HD of the laptop i am typing on... they will be transfered to an external HD and then to another internal HD

Comment: @FrankThomas couldnt i generate a hash from the files that are already on my PCs HD before transfering to the external hd?

Comment: yes, if you have a trustworthy copy.

Comment: @FrankThomas i would assume that this is an entirely separate issue that shouldnt be discussed on this post, correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the source disk, generate md5 hashes:

```
md5sum *.avi >my_avi_files.md5
```

This will generate a file with one line for each file.  Each line contains the md5sum and the file's name.  An example of such a file is:

```
58ba3b679b03c1deb6e30918311af726  boxed-correct.avi
cecfda865db60d3cf09a68c7f2030e9e  boxed-delete.avi
c373735b9c231d86244b28f3be9403e8  boxed-join.avi
63c3a103071507aa90b1353f42eead8d  boxed-split.avi
```

On the target disk, verify integrity by running:

```
md5sum -c  my_avi_files.md5
```

This will check each file listed in `my_avi_files.md5` individually.

#### What about subdirectories?

As an example of working with files in subdirectories, use this on the source directory:

```
md5sum *.avi */*.avi >my_avi_files.md5
```

This might produce output like:

```
a99f357d1f52eb8437e0572e98ebb012  FlickAnimation.avi
58ba3b679b03c1deb6e30918311af726  en-US/boxed-correct.avi
cecfda865db60d3cf09a68c7f2030e9e  en-US/boxed-delete.avi
```

On the target directory, the check is done the same way:

```
md5sum -c  my_avi_files.md5
```

While doing this check, `md5sum` expects to find the same files in the same subdirectories.  If you have changed the subdirectory names, you may edit the `my_avi_files.md5` file and update the paths using any normal text editor.

If your files are spread over many levels of subdirectories, use `find`:

```
find . -name '*.avi' -type f -exec md5sum {} + >my_avi_files.md5
```

#### Alternatives to md5

While md5 has long been the standard for this type of check, another option is `sha1sum`.  It works the same way:

```
sha1sum *.avi >my_avi_files.sha1
sha1sum -c my_avi_files.sha1
```

sha1 offers [better protection](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19705/is-sha1-better-than-md5-only-because-it-generates-a-hash-of-160-bits) against black hats who attempt file forgeries.

Comment: will this generate a single hash for all the files? or will i need seperate hashes for each file?

Comment: If I read this correctly, it will generate hashes for all .avi files in the folder where you run md5sum and store them in my_avi_files.md5. Conversely, all files need to be in the same place on the target disk for md5sum -vc to compare hashes.

Comment: @DoktoroReichard will this work for folders and sub-folders? or would ALL the actual files need to be in the same directory? (given the same folder/file structure as the source)

Comment: @KonnerRasmussen See updated answer for your first question,  Also, it will work if even for files in subdirectories but the source and target must have the same directory structure.  (Otherwise, you have to edit the `.md5` to correct the paths.)

Comment: @John1024 thank you =) i will try it and check your answer if all works out...

Comment: It doesn't recursively handle subfolders, if that's what you're asking - for that I would do something like `find . -name \*.avi -type f -exec md5sum '{}' \; > hashes.md5`. (At least I think that should work, I haven't tested it.) EDIT: it works.

Comment: @user55325 i used `md5sum /*/*.avi > check.md5` and it seems to be working. since all the files are only one folder deep it seems to be the proper course of action... thoughts? (i would praise you for the suggestion but that all is just a wee bit over my expertise... probably time to learn the ins and outs of bash scripts)

Comment: Yes, I didn't see the most recent edit. His solution will be fine for you, but mine works for any depth of subdirectories.

Comment: @user55325 Good thought.  I incorporated your idea into the answer (with the minor change of using the `-exec...+` form to avoid spawning so many processes).